# MouseEntered/Exited not fired when hovering over adjacent nodes

Tags: java, javafx-3d

I have two `javafx.scene.shape.Box` instances which are placed right adjacent to each other:

[image]

I would like to be notified whenever the picked node changes, i.e. whenever the mouse is entering or exiting the red or blue node.

Moving the mouse from black to any of the colored boxes correctly triggers a "mouse entered" event (and vice-versa, from red/blue to black fires a "mouse exited" event).

However, moving the mouse from red directly to blue (or from blue directly to red) does not trigger any events.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Box redBox = new Box(100, 100, 100);
        redBox.setId("red");
        redBox.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.RED));
        redBox.setTranslateX(100);
        redBox.setTranslateY(100);
        redBox.setTranslateZ(20);

        Box blueBox = new Box(100, 100, 100);
        blueBox.setId("blue");
        blueBox.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
        blueBox.setTranslateX(200);
        blueBox.setTranslateY(100);
        blueBox.setTranslateZ(20);

        PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);
        pointLight.setTranslateX(800);
        pointLight.setTranslateY(-100);
        pointLight.setTranslateZ(-1000);

        Group root = new Group(redBox, blueBox);
        root.getChildren().add(pointLight);

        root.setOnMouseEntered(me -> {
            System.out.println("Entered " + resolvePickedId(me));
        });

        root.setOnMouseExited(me -> {
            System.out.println("Exited " + resolvePickedId(me));
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.rgb(10, 10, 40));
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera(false));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static String resolvePickedId(MouseEvent me) {
        Node intersectedNode = me.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
        return intersectedNode == null ? "(none)" : intersectedNode.getId();
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to add a `MouseListener` to `blueBox` and `redBox` instead of `root`. When you add the `MouseListener` to `root` you only get notified when leaving/entering `root` hence no event when changing the element inside your `root` element.

Comment: Wow, this is embarrassing ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You set up a `Group root` of those two boxes, and whenever you `enter` or `exit` this group, your event gets triggered. Thats what is happening. Since both boxes are children of the Group, you won't get notified, because your Listener is looking for the Group, not for it's children.

Either you create a `MouseListener` directly to the boxes, or you can do something like track the current node, and check `OnMouseMoved` for a change:

```
//in the class, new variable
Node save = null;

//.... in the start method

root.setOnMouseEntered(me -> {
    System.out.println("Entered " + resolvePickedId(me));
    save = me.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
});

root.setOnMouseMoved(me ->{
    if(me.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode() != save){
        System.out.println("Changed to "+resolvePickedId(me));
        save = me.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
    }
});

root.setOnMouseExited(me -> {
    System.out.println("Exited " + resolvePickedId(me));
    save = null;
});
```